# merge python script and data (command) file into single .py file

Tags: python

Below scrip reads lines of commands to execute from a cmdAll.txt. Is there a way that I merge the command file into the script file itself. I remember I have seen such data blocks using <<EOF somewhere but I am not sure how to do it.

myScript.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
i=1
import enms
s = enms.open()
with open('cmdAll.txt') as f:
    for cmd in f:
        r = s.terminal().execute(cmd)
        filename = "output_%d.txt" % i
        fp = open(filename, 'w')
        for line in r.get_output():
            print line
            fp.write(line + "\n")
        fp.close()
        i+=1
f.close()
enms.close(s)
```

cmdAll.txt file:

```
cmget get * en.(enbid) -t
cmget get * gn.(gnbid) -t
cmget get * gnssinfo.(latitude,longitude) --table
cmget get * GpsSyncRef.(latitude,longitude) --table
```

Comment: Can't you just inline the string and split newlines?

Comment: I know that solution, however I am interested in that block data file, as the number of commands may be hundred lines...

Comment: Is it just a static file that never changes? Or is it dependent on input/things? 1000s of lines is not really a problem, it won't take more than a few MB of memory.

Comment: the commands changes and if I inline them the script will be messy. The solution I am asking is to clean up the code and data in single file easy to maintain each time the list of commands changes. no performance concerns here.

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? It looks very clean...

Comment: Also, what exactly does `terminal().execute()` do? If it's trying to run a system-agnostic command, you'd better stay away from things like heredoc.

Comment: You most likely don't want `line + "\n"` unless `get_output` is stripping your lines.

Comment: Are there python API docs for eNMS? I couldn't find any on the readthedocs site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `<<EOF` bit you saw somewhere had to do with [running Python in a shell script](https://trstringer.com/python-in-shell-script/) in a shell script, but you're asking for the inverse. You want your shell commands to live in your python script.

If you're not going to read the commands from a .txt file, and you would rather they live in the script, you might as well just make it clean and make a list out of them.

```
import enms

cmds = [
    "cmget get * en.(enbid) -t",
    "cmget get * gn.(gnbid) -t",
    "cmget get * gnssinfo.(latitude,longitude) --table",
    "cmget get * GpsSyncRef.(latitude,longitude) --table"
]

s = enms.open()
for cmd in cmds:
    r = s.terminal().execute(cmd)
```

If you prefer the commands exist as a single string, you could do something like this, where you are splitting on newlines. Just as Eric Jin suggested

```
import enms

comds = '''cmget get * en.(enbid) -t
cmget get * gn.(gnbid) -t
cmget get * gnssinfo.(latitude,longitude) --table
cmget get * GpsSyncRef.(latitude,longitude) --table'''

s = enms.open()
for cmd in cmds.split("\n"):
    r = s.terminal().execute(cmd)
```